# The type of one of the expression in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have a promblem with Linq-To-Sql

Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'

```
var conditionsFound = (from QuantiReports.Data.RoomInspectionGuid test in tests
                       where test.roomfloorid == obj.floorroomId                                               
                       join testItem in testItems //This join statement has an error

                       on new { roomItemId = obj.roomitemId, testId = test.id } equals new { roomItemId = testItem.roomitemid.Value, testId = testItem.roominspectionid }
                                           join testsCondition in testsConditions
                                           on new { conditionId = condition.id, testitemId = testItem.id } equals new { conditionId = testsCondition.conditionId, testitemId = testsCondition.roomItemInspectionId }
                                           select testsCondition).Count();
```

Comment: The error is actually inside the `on new { ... }` part.

Comment: your syntax is wrong, join should be before where

Comment: Ehsan is right and try to change `==` to `equal`

Comment: Mike Eason is right the error is in "new { roomItemId = obj.roomitemId, testId = test.id } equals new { roomItemId = testItem.roomitemid.Value, testId = testItem.roominspectionid } join testsCondition in testsConditions" "obj.roomitemId" and "testItem.roomitemid.Value" should be of same type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from syntax , can you check in second join expression "**on new { conditionId = condition.id**". Check if type "**condition**" is defined or not.